# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry

Tags: 7, nodes, feeds

Can any one help me with this? I'm not sure what's causing my feeds importer to fail on import.

I have debugged the saving function of the feed item found out it's trying to insert the node twice but not sure how to get around it or fix it so i don't run into the issue.

Throwed exception:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]:
  Integrity constraint violation:
    1062 Duplicate entry 'node-284' for key 'PRIMARY':
      INSERT INTO
        {feeds_item} (entity_type, entity_id, id, feed_nid, imported, url, guid, hash)
      VALUES (
        :db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2,
        :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5,
        :db_insert_placeholder_6, :db_insert_placeholder_7
      );
Array (
  [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => node
  [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => 284
  [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => feedback_importer
  [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => 55 
  [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 1363973130
  [:db_insert_placeholder_5] =>
  [:db_insert_placeholder_6] =>
  [:db_insert_placeholder_7] => 725208b7e0c7068d723d1488df2ffc31
 )
 in drupal_write_record() (line 7106 of (...)\includes\common.inc).
```

See also http://drupal.org/node/1950422.

Comment: Did you find something regarding this ?

Comment: No we didn't. We ended up turning off the unique id of the table row. It's not a great solution but it doesn't seem to affect the application in any bad way since the data in that table is temporary.